# [proto]: Importing the proto file in VSCode got not found error by IDE

Tags: visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers, proto

Simply I have these directories

[image]

in proof.proto I am **importing** the common_message.proto to be able to use the predefined message and **Everything works fine** -> [**compiling proto** files with **no problem**]

but the only thing that annoys me is that my vs-code always show this to me

[image]

and I am using the

[image]

as my linter extension

**NOTE**: that I am compiling proto files with protoc with no problems the importation has no errors (all good) but the error on IDE kinda annoy me

I want to know that if there is a way that I can get rid of the error?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can solve the problem by set up "protoc" options.

Go into `settings > Extensions > vscode-proto3 configuration` and then click `Edit in settings.json`. (you can just edit `.vscode/settings.json` too.)

After that, give `--proto_path` options like below codes.

```
{
    "protoc": {
        "options": [
            "--proto_path=<path of your proto files>"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: this option works IDE-wide, and if you add your proto source path hardcoded this way, it breaks once you switch working on another project.

Comment: You can actually user this option in a per-workspace basis if you add it to your `.vscode/settings.json` file.

Comment: Where is the root loaded from? For example ```--proto_path=src``` doesn't work. Maybe give an example?

Comment: @OliverDixon The absolute path of the directory containing the proto files (e.g., Users/user/Documents/...) worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the proto_path to the "proto" directory, it may work for every project if you are using that dir or subdir, works for me and I have several subdir/proto in my project.

[image: proto_path example]

Comment: Posting a screenshot instead of code ....

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one actually gave a complete answer. Jaylee didn't give an example of where the directory loads from.

Create a ".vscode/settings.json" directory and file inside the project.

Add this:

```
{
    "rust-analyzer.showUnlinkedFileNotification": false,
    "protoc": {
        "options": [
            "--proto_path=${workspaceRoot}/src"
        ]
    }
}
```

This is project specific so it won't work across other projects.

You can set this globally but that is not advised.